# External http endpoint worker role, no acces right with executionContext elevated

Tags: wcf, http, azure, azure-worker-roles

Yet another post on http service on worker role.

Hello everyone,

I have been looking everywhere for an answer and I can't find any.

Here is the problem :

I have a worker role with a tcp entry point. It works fine locally and on azure. So far so good.

I have a windows phone app (sdk 8.0, .net 4.5) that I want to connect to this endpoint.

First problem here, the only way to access a wcf service with a windows phone project is to Right-click project, "Add service reference" and put the service address. BUT ! it doesn't work with tcp.net://{address}:{port}/{service name}.
I've searched and found that I need a http service.

All right then, I'll create a http endpoint. Code is easy, can be found everywhere.

Now here's the interesting part, I have the following error :

> HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/myservice. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace.

So I've looked it up on the internet and found 2 answers :
adding

> `<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />`

to the ServiceDefinition.csdef file.
And setting

> `var binding = new BasicHttpBinding { HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact };`

Now here's the kicker, **I've done that and it still doesn't work.**

Here are my Endpoints in ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

> `<Endpoints>
>         <InputEndpoint name="External" protocol="tcp" port="10100" />
>         <InputEndpoint name="Http" protocol="http" port="8080" />
>   </Endpoints>`

Looking for help.